# How do I set up my Windows laptop's web server (XAMPP or IIS) to be accessible wirelessly (no router involved)

Tags: wireless-networking, webserver

I want to serve up web pages from my Windows 7 or 8 (I have two) laptop to nearby devices via WiFi.

I've got:

- VirtualRouterPlus set up to provide wireless access to my laptop.   *
- Xampp set up serving pages.

I"m not sure what address I need to use to accesss the pages on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading through [this article](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1173). It will provide you with answers to the question you've asked and a fair number of additional questions that you haven't asked yet. Look at the Basic Questions section.

Secondly, find out the ip address to your laptop(s) as seen by the devices you want to connect with. In Windows, this is something like `Win + R`, `cmd`, `Enter`then type `ipconfig /all`.

```
 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.com
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AA-BB-CC-DD-00-11
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : [redacted]
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.XXX.XXX
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, April 22, 2013 9:03:37 AM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, May 02, 2013 9:03:38 AM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 999999999
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : [redacted]
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
                                   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
     NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : redacted
```

I would look for the IPv4 address. Then do something like this: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/default.htm

Let me know if you have any further questions.